# How can avoid firing multiple times an onClick event when the user presses the button more than once really quick?

Tags: android, onclick

In `Android`, if the user presses a button multiple times really quick the `onClick` event is fired multiple times.. which kind of makes sense.

If the `onClick` method starts a new `Activity`, the user can open the same `Activity` multiple times and each instance of the `Activity` will be piled on top of the stack.

I usually disable the button inside the `onClick` method (associated to the button) and enable it again a couple of seconds after with the use of a `Handler` and `postDelay`.

I don't really like doing it in this way so is there another way of approaching this problem in a more clean way?

Comment: ebable/disable the button seems good to me

Answer (score 1):

In the Activities case you could also pass an extra for your Intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

to avoid multiple starts.

Other way is to have a dummy boolean while you're managing the click that prevents multiple clicks.

**UPDATE with example:**

```
boolean processingClick = false;
Button b = new Button();
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!processingClick) {
            processingClick = true;

            //your code here

            processingClick = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will probably work in combination with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.. otherwise the activity is re-created with each onclick event. The dummy boolean approach works perfect, though I was expecting some kind of control from the Android API.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I think the problem here is the little delay in the startActivity method, but I don't know if there's something that the platform could do.

Comment: could someone please elaborate on how the dummy boolean method would be achieved? any example code? cheers.

Answer (score 0):

clean way:

After you click the button, if the thing you want to invoke is `null`, invoke it, otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Method for all Buttons in the Actitivty:

```
public void enableButtons(boolean doit){
    bXXX.setClickable(doit);
    ...
    ...
}
```

If using "implement OnClickListener"

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    enableButtons(false);
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.xxx:
            doWhatYouWant();
            break;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

OnResume activate your Buttons again...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    enableButtons(true);
}
```